# Xamarin Hot Reload does... Absolutely Nothing when Changes are Made

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a very UI centric application - in this application it is important (or event vital one can say) that I can actively preview my changes. Thankfully, Xamarin.Forms has Hot Reload - the perfect tool to get started to preview your changes!

I enabled hot reload in the 'Hot Reload' section in the options tab - I also enabled the 'Changes Made' (which is in preview) option to 'ON'.

I started my application - and I changed the text of a button... And...

Nothing.

I closed and reopened my app - and tried again... And... guess what?

Nothing.

Xamarin.Forms - come on!

This is a very annoying issue I've had on this specific application - it's taken away most of my day and I've just been fighting and fighting - and I have been unable to solve anything.

**What I tried to do:**

1. I tried to upgrade my Xamarin.Forms version to the latest - and that still did not solve anything.
2. I tried to enable and disable Hot Reload from the options menu - and that still did not solve anything.
3. I tried to close and reopen the solution - clean - and build - and you guess it: still I could not preview my changes.
4. I checked if I enabled it and it was enabled.
5. I checked my linker settings and they were as expected.

Images:

[image]

XAML code:

*I changed the background color to blue:*

```
 <Grid HeightRequest="100"
                              Margin="5"
                              BackgroundColor="White"
                              RowSpacing="2">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



                            <Label Grid.Row="0"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   TextColor="Blue"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   Text="{Binding EventTitle}"
                                   Margin="7"
                                   Padding="10,0" />


                            <Image Grid.Row="0"
                                   HeightRequest="125"
                                   VerticalOptions="Start"
                                   Margin="2,2,1,2"
                                   Aspect="AspectFill"
                                   Source="{Binding Image}" />


                        </Grid>
```

My phone:

[image]

Even after saving - and waiting for at least half an hour - still the background is white.

I've tried everything possible to get it to work and I've been hitting the wall each time.

I am looking for help,

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload#troubleshooting

Comment: I have tried all of that I can assure you

Comment: @Cfun I am using Visual Studio 2019 - latest version.

Comment: Are you expecting the changes on the emulator or in the previewer ?

Comment: @Cfun on my physical device.

Comment: @Cfun debug... as I always do

Comment: @Cfun the funny thing is that it works in some other projects - but in this project Xamarin.Forms randomly decided it wasn't going to work.

Comment: Have you tried with "full page" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225883/discussion-between-tommy99-and-cfun).

Comment: Still getting issues with Hot reload in Visual Studio for Mac. Tried to uninstall the app from the Iphone, rebuild the solution, delete bin/obj, restarted VS for mac, restarted machine, nothing works. Not sure why they removed the preview feature?

Answer (score 4):

I've had all sorts of different issues with Hot Reload not working over the past few months.

I found the only consistent way that I could get it to work was by opening the project the long way around.

So:

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Choose Continue without code on the startup screen
3. Go to File -> Open -> Project/Solution and choose the solution from there.

Whenever I load the project this way, Hot Reload will work. If I load it any other way, it seems to be really temperamental.

Comment: Sorry... does not work whatsoever @Gaz Winter - don't know what's up. :/ This is primarily one of the reasons I'm transitioning away from Xamarin.Forms and to native development - Xamarin.Forms needs a lot of work and is hardly refined. Appreciate your answer though.

Comment: @tommy99 Have you tried with a complete new solution? Have you tried if it is working on emulator? Have you tried repair your visual studio in visual studio installer ?

Comment: yes I have done everything and I've been stuck for days just to get this to work @Cfun ... you won't believe the hours I put into it... just to see my changes...

Comment: @Cfun I will stick with the CTRL + S way of doing things for now I guess.

Comment: @tommy99 Is there anything in the Output/Debug window?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open project
2. Go to Tools => Debugging => Hot Reload
3. On "Common" section tick "Apply XAML hot reload on document save"
4. on "Xamarin.Forms" section tick "Full Page"

as shown in the image (red circled below).[image: Hot reload solution]

Answer (score 0):

On a project had the same issue , found out that i have to be in a XAML page
and not a XAML.CS page

Then hit save and it starts again and oke.

Common options - only Enable Just My XAML in Live Visual Tree

And in Xamarin.Forms option -Full page

ps

On your example it is White

BackgroundColor="White"